# Java datastore batch delete entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, batch-processing, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to execute a batch delete. But, I cannot work out how to convert a list of entities to keys to then batch delete. Is there a special method available in datastore?

I'm trying to do:

```
Query q = new Query("ENTITY_NAME").setAncestor(key).setKeysOnly();
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
QueryResultIterable<Entity> result = pq.asQueryResultIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(500));

datastore.delete(result); // somehow convert iterable entities to iterable key??
```

What I have currently have:

```
Query q = new Query("ENTITY_NAME").setAncestor(key).setKeysOnly();
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
QueryResultIterable<Entity> result = pq.asQueryResultIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(500));
QueryResultIterator<Entity> iterator = result.iterator();

// delete one at a time
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  datastore.delete(iterator.next().getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the code to the below, but I've not tested it yet and I'm not sure if there is a better way:

```
List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();
QueryResultIterator<Entity> iterator = result.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  keys.add(iterator.next().getKey());
}

datastore.delete(keys);
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have more than 1,000 entities in one batch.

Comment: I'm also using FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(500), to fetch the items.